# Should I only be loading Javascript files on pages I need them?

Tags: php, javascript, optimization

So I am starting to get interested in Optimization and I was wondering if it is worth it to only include the Javascript files in the pages I need and exclude them from the rest using PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading only the scripts you need will definitely help.

Another huge improvement can be made by combining all javascript to one file and (if possible) minimizing and caching the output. The less requests a browser has to make, the faster your page will load.

Comment: +1 A good point.  If the site has wildly differing Javascript requirements per page, it may necessitate on-the-fly generation to have a single script delivered, but it does help page load time.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to convert the studio I work at to start minifying and combining all their files. I guess this question mostly relates to remote API's.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, **yes**.

Each page should not load more than it needs.  Minimising traffic is always good.

It is a good idea to have a framework for generating pages, and only add the resources you need for each page.

Comment: To expand on this, it's also a good practice to avoid unloading any resources between pages.

Comment: How do you mean by avoid unloading resources, isn't that the opposite what we are doing here? E.g You are on the Homepage that requires foo.js and you go to about us which doesn't require foo.js. Are we not supposed to remove foo.js on the about us page?

Answer (score 1):

If you include all or most of the JavaScript that your site needs on your main page (in an minimized and compressed form like what is provided by [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)) it will increase the load time of your main page but will decrease the load time of every other page because the JavaScript will already be in cache.  A lot of web applications will use this technique so that the user experience after the initial load is smoother.

Either technique has its merits, it really just depends on the type of application/page you are building.  But like dirkbonhomme said you should be minimizing, compressing, and caching the JavaScript (and CSS) no matter which way you go.

Comment: I've used YUI Compressor for a long time, but recently got interested in the Google Closure Compiler, worth a look: http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

Comment: So on the home page we include all our Javascript regardless if it requires it or not? Then on the other pages we only include whatever ones we need.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I got a little busy.  You don't want to include all of the JavaScript on the first page and only what you need on every other page if you are compressing, that means your JavaScript files will be different and they will re-download.  Instead, you include all of your JavaScript on every page.  Remember, it is all compressed in a single file, the contents of that file is what is being cached.  If you are not compressing everything in one file then got with the method of just including what you need.